# JavaFx create HatchStyles (something like of C# .Net)

Tags: c#, canvas, javafx, hatchstyle

Is there anything similar to .Net [HatchStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for filling shapes when using [scene shape objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/package-summary.html) or drawing on JavaFx Canvas (in jdk, third party libraries, sample codes, etc)?

The only solution I currently can think of is using an [ImagePattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html) created via Image screenshots of those .net  hatchstyles!

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(new Image("dotnet-pattern.png");
gc.setFill(pattern);
```

graphical representation of .Net hatch styles:
[image]

Comment: Depending on what you need, clever uses of [`LinearGradient`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) might work. AFAIK (I know nothing about C#) there is no direct equivalent. Note for `ImagePattern` you can also create the underlying `Image` as a `WritableImage` or even a [`snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) of, say, a `Pane` containing `Shape` instances.

Comment: JPG is not be the best image format to do this, since it's lossy. If you're using that approach, you're better of using `.png`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be a slight modification of what you suggested: use an `ImagePattern`, but [`snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) an appropriate node for the underlying image.

Without actually knowing what the `HatchStyle`s look like, variations on the following might work:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.ImagePattern;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HatchStyleCanvas extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Image hatch = createHatch();
        ImagePattern pattern = new ImagePattern(hatch, 0, 0, 20, 20, false);        
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 600);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(pattern);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(canvas)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Image createHatch() {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefSize(20, 20);
        Line fw = new Line(-5, -5, 25, 25);
        Line bw = new Line(-5, 25, 25, -5);
        fw.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        bw.setStroke(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        fw.setStrokeWidth(5);
        bw.setStrokeWidth(5);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(fw, bw);
        new Scene(pane);
        return pane.snapshot(null, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This results in

[image]

Comment: thanks! It's much better than using screenshots and I think there is no better solution, I decompiled .Net code and found out it uses GDI+ for painting HatchSytles so even porting the code is not an option.