# How to use Hatched fill colors in javaFX?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, colors

I'm working on JavaFx canvas.
I can have a GraphicsContext object called 'gc'.

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
```

I can set regular fill color for it as

```
gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
```

But I really want is HATCHED green color as the fill.
But I couldn't found appropriate java class to get Hatched Colors.
Can anybody help me please?

Hera is an Example for hatched patterns(color=black in this case):-
[image: An Example for hatched patterns(color=black in this case)]

Comment: relevant: [JavaFx equivalent of C# .Net HatchStyles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297719/javafx-equivalent-of-c-sharp-net-hatchstyles)

Comment: Also related (though different): [Resizable Grid using Canvas](http://fxexperience.com/2014/05/resizable-grid-using-canvas/).

Comment: The duplicate is about JavaFX, not C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fill to an [ImagePattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/ImagePattern.html), or a [Gradient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) to achieve the hatch.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.!